# PHP - Anonymous function inside an object

Tags: php

**This will return error:**

FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::myfunc() in /var/www/html/index.php81(4) : eval()'d code:10 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php81(4): eval() #1 {main} thrown on line number 10

**How can I make this work?**

```
<?php
$data = (object) [];

$data->foo = "whatever";

$data->myfunc = function () {
    echo "Yeah";
};

$data->myfunc(); // this makes error

call_user_func($data->myfunc); // this works as expected, strange
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your last line to this:

```
($data->myfunc)();
```

This is because the $data->myfunc() syntax refers to actual member functions on the object.
So to first evaluate the property myfunc (this evaluates to a function) and then evaluate the function, you have to wrap it in parenthises or alternativly parse the property to a local variable before calling it as a function.